# Problem launching moveit_setup_assistant in groovy

Tags: moveit, roslaunch, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed **moveit** on groovy (Ubuntu 12.04) and I want to follow their tutorials. The first step is to launch the `moveit_setup_assistant` and I failed in the this very first step. When I run this command (suggested by moveit Wiki)

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

I receive this error:

```
[moveit_setup_assistant] is not a package or launch file name
```

Why this happens and how should I tackle this problem? It might be worth mentioning that while typing the command, `tab complition` works properly and completes both parts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53923/problem-launching-moveit_setup_assistant-in-groovy/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-01**:
To be clear, you used the instructions provided at http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/Installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source devel/setup.bash in the terminal where you issued your command?

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1